# Firefox 37 & Selenium Webdriver 2.45

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

Are there any known compatibility issues with Firefox 37 & Webdriver 2.45? I am currently using Firefox 36 and Webdriver 2.45 (having had trouble with the prior release of Webdriver). Firefox is requesting that I update to 37.

Answer (score 4):

Better don't do that, in my case after updating firefox to 37 - web driver 2.45 cannot start firefox session...So need to wait for web driver release.

Answer (score 0):

We updated FireFox yesterday to 37.0.1 using selenium-java:2.45.0 from Maven and we have had no issues with any of our tests